# SQL SERVER: JOIN 2 already joined sections of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I already LEFT JOINed many tables into two sections, but now how do I join these two together?
I am not sure if subquery would work but at least I tried subquery its very confused/

[image]

```
SELECT MoviePerson.PersonId, MoviePerson.PersonFirstName, MoviePerson.PersonLastName, MoviePersonRole.RoleId FROM MoviePerson
LEFT JOIN MoviePersonRole ON MoviePerson.PersonId = MoviePersonRole.PersonId;

select DVD.DVDId, DVD.GenreId, DVD.RatingId, DVD.DVDTitle, DVD.DVDReleasedate, DVD.TheaterReleaseDate, Genre.GenreName, Rating.RatingName,
Rating.RatingDescription
from DVD
LEFT join Genre on DVD.GenreId = Genre.GenreID
LEFT JOIN Rating ON DVD.RatingId = Rating.RatingId
LEFT JOIN MoviePersonRole ON DVD.DVDId =MoviePersonRole.DVDId
;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63aa0140d397056e4bbd14a6cf6517ed)

Comment: Sample data and expected results as *text* would help immensely

Comment: do you know what kind of  term of this sameple data is? @charlieface

Comment: We'd like sample data (say a few rows) as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. A https://DBFiddle.uk would be nice too

Comment: The easy/lazy way is to put each query into a CTE and then join the CTEs. But your second query already joins to MoviePersonRole - just add the join to MoviePerson as needed. Do you really need all those left joins? Think about what your query should return as a resultset and how you intend to use that resultset.

Comment: the sample data are relatively long, here's the link for them: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MR3lOFZMwULfitYn6KZbnnMXdYLOFUZa/view?usp=sharing @charlieface

Comment: Just add a few lines of it to your question, along with expected results. You can't expect people to download a `rar` file from an unknown source

Comment: the webpage doesnt allow me put all codes, so I seprated the scripts: 
1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14P-TEIKFRSbfPjTXysI-GQ2owMs-0_MQ/view?usp=sharing 
2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qIqunomUR5OX4V5ucykJZdE4-Ogfvhjl/view?usp=sharing
3: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bGK8OlOdNX9gTp02f3Lz7hBBqDyYoKKu/view?usp=sharing
@charlieface

Comment: OK I've done you a favour and created a fiddle. Please [edit] your question and add expected results

Comment: this was the first thing I had tried but the stackoverflow system just gave me a ! mark for nonsense to prevent me upload! !!@charlieface

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look as though you have a column to join on.  If you did, you could use the following syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT MoviePerson.PersonId, MoviePerson.PersonFirstName, MoviePerson.PersonLastName, MoviePersonRole.RoleId FROM MoviePerson
LEFT JOIN MoviePersonRole ON MoviePerson.PersonId = MoviePersonRole.PersonId;
) X
INNER JOIN
(
select DVD.DVDId, DVD.GenreId, DVD.RatingId, DVD.DVDTitle, DVD.DVDReleasedate, DVD.TheaterReleaseDate, Genre.GenreName, Rating.RatingName,
Rating.RatingDescription
from DVD
LEFT join Genre on DVD.GenreId = Genre.GenreID
LEFT JOIN Rating ON DVD.RatingId = Rating.RatingId
LEFT JOIN MoviePersonRole ON DVD.DVDId =MoviePersonRole.DVDId
) Y
ON X.column_to_join = y.column_to_join
```